# Covering points with circles

Tags: geometry

This might be a very basic question for some of you, but I don't know how to solve it.

I have a set of 14 points distributed in a 2D plane. I have to cover them using the minimum number of circles of radius R. The circles can be overlapped.

Is there an algorithm or a theory that I can use?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705922/finding-a-cover-of-a-set-of-points-with-circles